# Generated a list of filenames but no file paths

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using wpf in C# with caliburn micro mvvm. I have a list box that displays a set of filenames that references tsv files. I modified the file names to something else as required in the project.

However now when the item is selected, the path is completely lost. How can I modify the file name to whatever I want but still retain the filepath?

Comment: You will have to create a class with a property for the display value, and a property for the "real" value.

Comment: Thanks. After I create a class, how do I show the full path in the textbox? Sorry I am new to wpf, mvvm and caliburn micro

Comment: You would bind the list to the listbox, and set the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the listbox to the name of the property that contains the text you want to display in the list.  Then you can use the `SelectedItem` property, and cast it to your class, and look at the property for the full path.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked!